# TB_SETPADDING message has no effect on vertical padding

Tags: windows, winapi, button, toolbar

I an trying to set the toolbar padding to zero, but the `TB_SETPADDING` message effect only to the horizontal padding, but not to the vertical padding.

I set the color scheme to red and green, to highlight the button border, and this is the output:

[image]

can someone explain me why is this happening?

this is the full code:

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "comctl32.lib")

#define IDB_PRINT 40000

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
HINSTANCE instance;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    instance = hInstance;

    WNDCLASSEX wcex; 

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style           = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW; 
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc; 
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0; 
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;  
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));  
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW); 
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1); 
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = NULL; 
    wcex.lpszClassName  = L"Example"; 
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));

    RegisterClassEx(&wcex);

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(L"Example", L"", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        500, 500, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    // Initialize common controls.
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex;
    icex.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    icex.dwICC   = ICC_COOL_CLASSES | ICC_BAR_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&icex);

    // create toolbar
    HWND hToolbar = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | TBSTYLE_EX_HIDECLIPPEDBUTTONS, TOOLBARCLASSNAME, NULL, CCS_NODIVIDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CCS_ADJUSTABLE | TBSTYLE_ALTDRAG | TBSTYLE_FLAT | TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS,
        0, 0, 0, 0, hWnd, (HMENU)0, instance, NULL);

    SendMessage(hToolbar, TB_SETMAXTEXTROWS, 0, 0);

    // create image list
    HIMAGELIST hImageList = ImageList_Create(20,20, ILC_COLORDDB, 4, 0);
    ImageList_Add(hImageList, LoadBitmap(instance, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDB_PRINT)), NULL);
    ImageList_Add(hImageList, LoadBitmap(instance, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDB_PRINT)), NULL);

    // set the image list
    SendMessage(hToolbar, TB_SETIMAGELIST, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)hImageList);
    SendMessage(hToolbar, TB_BUTTONSTRUCTSIZE, (WPARAM)sizeof(TBBUTTON), 0);

    // create button
    TBBUTTON tbb[1] = 
    { 
        {0, 0, TBSTATE_ENABLED, BTNS_AUTOSIZE, {0}, 0, (INT_PTR)L"Print"},
    };

    // add button to the toolbar
    SendMessage(hToolbar, (UINT)TB_ADDBUTTONS, 1, (LPARAM)&tbb);
    SendMessage(hToolbar, TB_SETBUTTONSIZE, 0, MAKELPARAM(20, 20));
    SendMessage(hToolbar, TB_AUTOSIZE, 0, 0);
    DWORD res = SendMessage(hToolbar, TB_SETPADDING, 0, MAKELPARAM(0, 0));

    // set color scheme to red and green
    COLORSCHEME cs;
    cs.dwSize = sizeof(cs);
    cs.clrBtnShadow = RGB(255, 0, 0);
    cs.clrBtnHighlight = RGB(0, 255, 0);
    SendMessage(hToolbar, TB_SETCOLORSCHEME, 0, (LPARAM)&cs);

    // set the padding size to zero
    SendMessage(hToolbar, TB_SETPADDING, 0, MAKELPARAM(0, 0));

    // show the toolbar
    ShowWindow(hToolbar, SW_SHOW);

    // show the main window
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    MSG msg;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);  
        DispatchMessage(&msg); 
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_CREATE: 
            return 0;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

=== EDIT ===

this what I have in my resource file:

```
#define IDB_PRINT 40000
IDB_PRINT BITMAP "print.bmp"
```

and this is the `print.bmp` file:
[image]

Comment: It would not be that surprising if padding was simply not supported in vertical mode, quite often the common controls are not properly tested in all combinations/permutations.

Comment: the toolbar is not in vertical mode

Comment: Padding only applies when the TBSTYLE_AUTOSIZE style is in effect.  Not the case here.  Pretty undiagnosable without having the resources.  Do make sure that your screen shot is produced by your code snippet, the toolbar button isn't 20x20 for some reason.

Comment: @Hans - `TBSTYLE_AUTOSIZE` is for version 4.72 and earlier, I am using Windows XP, so I need use `BTNS_AUTOSIZE`, as I did at this line of code `{0, 0, TBSTATE_ENABLED, BTNS_AUTOSIZE, {0}, 0, (INT_PTR)L"Print"}`, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760439(v=vs.85).aspx). // and I edited my question, so you can get my resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is the size of the toolbar window, not the size of the buttons.

If you call `CreateWindowEx` and include the `CCS_NORESIZE` style, this disables the default sizing behaviour of the toolbar window. [As MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#CCS_NORESIZE)

[image]

This is the technique that [MSDN recommends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760443%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Specifying_Toolbar_Size_and_Position) when toolbars are hosted by rebar controls

[image: rebar]

It's obviously more of a pain that you have to resize and reposition the toolbar "manually" when necessary, but it does allow you to create your window to get the desired effect. For example, specify a fixed width and height on creation (and apply the `CCS_NORESIZE` style)

```
// create toolbar
HWND hToolbar = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | TBSTYLE_EX_HIDECLIPPEDBUTTONS, TOOLBARCLASSNAME, NULL, 
    CCS_NORESIZE | CCS_NODIVIDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CCS_ADJUSTABLE | TBSTYLE_ALTDRAG | TBSTYLE_FLAT | TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS,
    0, 0, 500, 21, hWnd, (HMENU)0, instance, NULL);
```

This is a blown-up screenshot like your original example, but with the above change (height set to 21 to accommodate 1px y offset)

[image]

To force the toolbar button to be exactly 20x20 and to remove the padding at the top of the button, it's possible to also use the `CCS_NOPARENTALIGN` style and then set the window origin to a negative y value and extend the height accordingly.

For example, this code

```
// create toolbar
HWND hToolbar = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | TBSTYLE_EX_HIDECLIPPEDBUTTONS, TOOLBARCLASSNAME, NULL, 
    CCS_NORESIZE | CCS_NOPARENTALIGN | CCS_NODIVIDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CCS_ADJUSTABLE | TBSTYLE_ALTDRAG | TBSTYLE_FLAT | TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS,
    0, -2, 500, 22, hWnd, (HMENU)0, instance, NULL);
```

produces this result

[image: tbb2]

Comment: an easier solution would be to use TB_SETBUTTONSIZE to adjust the vertical size, rather than using padding that is not properly used most of the time